# How do I perform a high speed car jack?

Tags: sleeping-dogs

There is a control called "Active Hijack" which I have got bound to <kbd>Q</kbd>. This button makes me open my car door while I'm driving and as I pass cars an arrow highlights indicating I can jump onto that car, presumably to hijack it.

[image]

However, when I press the jump key, I faceplant into the back of the car and lose a lot of health.

How do I perform a high speed car jack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're hitting the jump button instead of the "Action Hijack" one to perform that final jump.

From the [official manual](http://cdn.eidosinteractive.com/mtl/marketing/SleepingDogs/SleepingDog_PC_ENG.pdf) or [steam manual](http://cdn4.steampowered.com/Manuals/202170/SD_Manual_EN.pdf?t=1387537163):

> While driving and approaching another car, you can use **left SHIFT** to
>   leap between the moving vehicles and perform an ACTION HIJACK. When
>   the white arrow pointing towards the target vehicle turns green, tap
>   the **left SHIFT** button to leap and take control of the other car.

Both manuals state that **left SHIFT** is the "Action Hijack" button but the in game default seems to be **Q** so just replace **left SHIFT** in the above with **Q** or, if manually remapped, whatever you have it mapped to.

Comment: Just so you know, the keys are completely incorrect. Left Shift is aiming, Q is action hijack.

Comment: @kotekzot Don't know if this has changed since release but I've just re-downloaded and it's Q now. Both manuals (official and Steam version) still state Left Shift though so I'm not going to misquote them. Merry Christmas!

Comment: You don't need to quote the manual, particularly when it's incorrect. Happy Christmas!

Comment: If the manual is wrong it's worth letting people know, especially if it relates specifically to something they're having trouble with.

Comment: As a side note at the end of an answer, sure, but not as the most prominent part of an answer that is then corrected at the bottom.

Answer (score 6):

The 'Action Hijack' key (Default <kbd>Q</kbd>) *is* the correct key, but there's a trick to it. Hit and hold <kbd>Q</kbd> to pull up the interface where Wei is hanging out of the car and the white arrow appears, then hit <kbd>Q</kbd> again when the arrow turns green. I hope this helps clarify the confusion for anyone in the future.